# Python fetch data 403

Tags: python, urllib2, fetch, http-status-code-403, httplib2

I am trying to fetch data from a webpage using urllib2. The page is visible on the browser but through the script I keep getting HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I also tried mimicking a browser request by changing the user-agent string but no success.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Does the site requires authentication? If yes how are users being tracked? Does the site uses cookies to track authenticated users? If yes you need to send a cookie along with your HTTP request.

Comment: Can you give some more details of the website and code which you are using to access the above mentioned site. It may not be an issue with User-Agent.

Comment: @Darin - no authemtication required. Cookies, i will have to check. This is the url of the page I am trying to fetch. http://www.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_underlyinglist.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with tamper data and firefox to send only user agent, and I get 403.
Try to add other headers:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
```

I tried, and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The site is checking your `User-Agent` just set it to `Internet Explorer`:

```
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Internet Explorer')
```

I confirmed that this works with `wget`, and you get 403 unless you set your user agent to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

:) Am trying to get quotes from NSE too ! like pythonFoo says you need additional headers. Hower only Accept is sufficient. 
The user-agent can say python ( stay true ! )